# how to find out if XMLHttpRequest.send() worked

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am using `XMLHttpRequest` to send a file from `javascript` code to a `django view`.I need to detect,whether the file has been sent or if some error occurred.I used jquery to write the following javascript.

Ideally I would like to show the user an error message that the file was not uploaded.Is there some way to do this in `javascript`?

I tried to do this by returning a `success/failure` message from `django view` , putting the `success/failed message` as `json` and sending back the serialized json from the `django view`.For this,I made the `xhr.open()`  `non-asynchronous`. I tried to print the `xmlhttpRequest` object's `responseText` .The `console.log(xhr.responseText)`  shows

```
response= {"message": "success"}
```

What I am wondering is,whether this is the proper way to do this.In many articles,I found the warning that

> Using async=false is not recommended

So,is there any way to find out whether the file has been sent,while keeping `xhr.open()` asynchronous?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('change', '#fselect', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            sendFile();
        });
});

function sendFile(){
   var form = $('#fileform').get(0);
   var formData = new FormData(form);
   var file = $('#fselect').get(0).files[0];
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   formData.append('myfile', file);
   xhr.open('POST', 'uploadfile/', false);
   xhr.send(formData);
   console.log('response=',xhr.responseText);
}
```

My `django` view extracts file from form data and writes to a destination folder.

```
def store_uploaded_file(request):
   message='failed'
   to_return = {}
   if  (request.method == 'POST'):          
      if request.FILES.has_key('myfile'):
         file = request.FILES['myfile']
         with open('/uploadpath/%s' % file.name, 'wb+') as dest:
            for chunk in file.chunks():
               dest.write(chunk)
               message="success"
   to_return['message']= message
   serialized = simplejson.dumps(to_return)
   if store_message == "success":
      return HttpResponse(serialized, mimetype="application/json")
   else:
      return HttpResponseServerError(serialized, mimetype="application/json")
```

EDIT:

I got this working with the help of @FabrícioMatté

```
xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
       if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
          console.log('xhr.readyState=',xhr.readyState);
          console.log('xhr.status=',xhr.status);
          console.log('response=',xhr.responseText);

          var data = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
          var uploadResult = data['message']
          console.log('uploadResult=',uploadResult);

          if (uploadResult=='failure'){
             console.log('failed to upload file');
             displayError('failed to upload');
          }else if (uploadResult=='success'){
             console.log('successfully uploaded file');
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: `xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200` doesn't suffice?

Comment: forgive my ignorance, if the filewriting in django view fails and server error occurs(500) ,can I detect that using `xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==500` ?

Comment: Provided your `xhr` object returns a response, it should contain the `status` and `readyState` properties as well. Try `console.log`ing those to make sure. =]

Comment: thanks @FabrícioMatté  ,I have updated the question with how I got this working..If you can convert the above comment to a reply ,I can accept it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` objects contain the `status` and `readyState` properties, which you can test in the `xhr.onreadystatechange` event to check if your request was successful.

Comment: the answer is updated with a working code snippet at the end.

Answer (score 25):

Something like the following code should do the job:

```js
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
          if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
             console.log('successful');
          } else {
             console.log('failed');
          }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`XMLHttpRequest` provides the ability to listen to various events that can occur while the request is being processed. This includes periodic progress notifications, error notifications, and so forth.

So:

```
function sendFile() {
   var form = $('#fileform').get(0);
   var formData = new FormData(form);
   var file = $('#fselect').get(0).files[0]
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   formData.append('myfile', file);
   xhr.open('POST', 'uploadfile/', false);
   xhr.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
   xhr.addEventListener("error", transferFailed);
  }

    function transferComplete(evt) {
        console.log("The transfer is complete.");
        // Do something
    }

    function transferFailed(evt) {
        console.log("An error occurred while transferring the file.");
        // Do something
    }
```

You can read more about [Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: It's unclear what the error event is supposed to do.
I've tried it in my browser's console. All requests, including failing ones, exclusively trigger the load event. I have no clue what triggers the error event. Readystate is probably a better match, considering it will actually tell you if your reuest succedded or not.