# xhr.send() does not trigger ajaxComplete/ajaxSuccess, but $.get does. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Imagine I have these three functions:

```
$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  console.log('ajaxSuccess fired');
});

function doCall1 () {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', 'someurl.com', true);
    xhr.send();
}

function doCall2 (){
    $.get('someurl.com');
}
```

When I call `doCall1`, `ajaxSuccess` does not fire. However, when I call `doCall2`, `ajaxSuccess` does fire.

I understand this is related to the fact jQuery is in fact using a callback function to various methods of $.ajax() rather than looking at onreadystatechange / readyState of the XMLHttpRequest (correct me if I'm off the mark), but I still don't completely understand.

Can someone give me a quick explanation or direct me to some docs that'd get me the rest of the way to getting this?

Comment: xhr.send isn't a jquery method, therefore jquery doesn't intercept it.

Comment: jQuery can only track AJAX requests made through jQuery methods. XHR is native JS.

Comment: you are setting up a jquery callback (ajaxSuccess) xhr isnt part of jquery, its native

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to find out if XMLHttpRequest.send() worked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876123/how-to-find-out-if-xmlhttprequest-send-worked)

Answer (score 4):

As others have noted, `ajaxSuccess` and `ajaxComplete` are non-native events added by jQuery. If for some reason you wanted interop between jQuery and vanilla js, you could dispatch the events yourself (with the caveat that browser support for [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) is limited):

```
var event = new CustomEvent("ajaxComplete");
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because the `ajaxSuccess` and `ajaxComplete` methods are part of jQuery and they are only triggered by the jQuery functions.

`XMLHttpRequest` is a native javascript object and its not related with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The code for triggering `ajaxSuccess`/`ajaxComplete` are written in the end of `$.ajax()`, `$.get()`, `$.post()`, etc. The above events are related to jQuery and the `$.ajax()`, `$.get()`, `$.post()` functions are jQuery functions.

The XHR is native JavaScript and is no way related to jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

the one thing is the jQuery object having deferrers and the other one a native JavaScript object, where you have to attach a callback yourself and may forward it to the ajaxSuccess of jQuery (jQ wraps the native XMLRequest object and does that).