# Execute a javascript function from HTTP Request

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to get a function work that I will get from an HTTP Get Request. However I can not make the script run

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.launch = function(url, has_credits) {
            if (has_credits != "True"){
                if (!confirm(con_str)){
                    window.close();
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("waiting_msg").innerHTML = "Loading..."
            location.href = url;
        };

        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        theUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/game/launch/?provider=XXX&game=7bal_tie&token=50c63444b85cdadf5e4b9285c2be5444&jsonp=launch'
        xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, true );
        xmlHttp.send( null );
        //
            // The script that will trigger  the function 
        //
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The return of the request is

```
launch("http://my-url.com","False");
```

Which should redirect me to the said url. I hope that javascript has a builtin function that can easily run it like

```
func(xmlHttp.response);
```

Then will just trigger the function but I can't find any and eval did not workout for me

Comment: You can see this question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876123/how-to-find-out-if-xmlhttprequest-send-worked . It can help you with this problem.

Comment: `eval` is what you are looking for (though this style of design is not recommended)

Comment: I have three words for you: VERY BAD IDEA

Comment: @ammoQ eval did not worked for me like eval(launch("http://my-url.com","False"));

Comment: @TanLe, I'm certain that my XMLHTTPRequest worked

Comment: @Bálint, can you suggest a good idea instead?

Comment: @Dean NEVER EVER evalueate javascript source code that's loaded from somewhere. What if the server gets compromised and makes the URL a link to a site that contains a virus. Or even worse, it sends a piece of code that steals passwords on your site.

Comment: Try `eval('launch("my-url.com")')` instead

Comment: Balint: on the other hand, all javascript is loaded from somewhere. As long as it is the same server the delivered the original page, no additional security risk is created.

Comment: Eval worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval` should work but it is very bad idea for anything more than a prototype. You haven't set a `responseType` but I presume that you want `responseText` rather than `response`. I'm not sure what type `response` will be but it might be a buffer or something like that, which is not what you want.

You could do something like this:

```
function reqListener () {
  if (xmlHttp.status !== 200) return;
  eval(this.responseText);
}

xmlHttp.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
```

But again, using `eval` is a bad idea. Let's imagine you change the API response to this instead:

```
{
  "func": "launch",
  "params": ["http://my-url.com", "False"]
}
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
function reqListener () {
  if (xmlHttp.status !== 200) return;
  var respObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  window[respObj.func].apply(window, respObj.params);
}

xmlHttp.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
```

This is still not ideal since it could be used to execute arbitrary code on the window object but it is a bit better than using `eval` directly since it limits the scope of the vulnerability.

The real answer to this question is that you should not leave your javascript open to the possibility of remote code execution. So don't use this code in production and redesign the API instead.

Comment: Actually I think this will be fine, as it only is for redirect and I just did not put it but the URL to be sent a request has tokens with it

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada I don't understand your comment. Can you give more detail and I'll let you know if I think it's safe or not.

Comment: this is an example url that I am trying to request, 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/game/launch/?provider=PT&game=7bal_tie&token=bece719ff48b3e213b851abc39444879&jsonp=launch'.. and what it does, is it will just redirect to a certain URL

httprespnse.text's value is launch('cache.games.com/client.html?game=7bal_tie&language=JP', 'False')

so the code that I am evaluating is

eval("launch('cache.games.com/client.html?game=7bal_tie&language=JP', 'False')") and eval did work thankyou

It is in the same IP and domain by the way,, My javascript and the backend that I am requesting

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't change any of the issues. Even something like a simple API error could prevent all further execution of JS on that page. Also `eval` is slow because it causes double interpretation. Anyway, as long as you're aware of the potential issues then go forth and use it.

Comment: Ok, string parsing then would be better and use window for parameters

Comment: Yes, it would be better to parse the response rather than blindly `eval()`ing it. It would also be better if your function wasn't stored directly on the window object and was instead scoped to a local object.