# XMLHttpRequest action after success

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form, the form has text fields and a canvas in it that preforms as a signiture pad.

[link to the form](http://davdev.co.il/sign/canvas4/)

I use `ajax` in order to send the form.
What I have troubles doing is to confirm that the form is inserted to the database.

I think that there is a collision between the ajax and the php I use in order to insert the form data to the mysql db
how can I do it?

This is the content of the js file

```
                var fd = new FormData(document.forms["form1"]);

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('POST', 'upload_data.php', true);

                xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {

                    if (e.lengthComputable) {
                        var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                        alert(percentComplete + '% uploaded');
                    }
                };


                xhr.onload = function() { 
                };


                xhr.send(fd);
```

This is the content of the  `upload_data.php` file:

```
<?php

    require 'inc/inc.php';

    $upload_dir = "upload/";
    $img = $_POST['hidden_data'];
    $idNo = $_POST['idno'];
    $name = $_POST['fname'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = $upload_dir . mktime() ."-" . $idNo . ".png";
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';


    $suc = new Form;
    $suc->insert_data($name, $file, $idNo);
    ?>
```

This is the `insert_data()`  php function content

```
public function insert_data($name, $file, $idNo){
            $query = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO signitures (name, file, idno) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"); 
            $query->bindparam(1, $name);
            $query->bindparam(2, $file);
            $query->bindparam(3, $idNo);



            try {

            $query->execute();
                if ($query) {
                   echo "success!! ";
                } else {
                     echo "Failure conncting db!";
                }
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
```

I know that if `$query->execute();` returns `true` than the data was inserted. 
How can I notify the user that the data was really inserted to the database? 
Even pass the user to a new page is an option. 
Actualy, redirect the user to a new page will be great!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find out if XMLHttpRequest.send() worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876123/how-to-find-out-if-xmlhttprequest-send-worked)

Comment: I don't know PHP so I can't give you implementation details, but the concept is simple. Once PHP is done querying the database, have it send a response to the client that requested insertion. You could simply use HTTP status codes, e.g. 200 if successfully inserted. Then read the response headers from JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you need to add in the function insert_data on the try{ at the end} a echo of your success to send to ajax script as response so a simple.

```
$success['success'] = "You request just sending to the server ...";
echo json_encode($success);
```

In your fonction ajax

```
            xhr.onload = function(data) { 
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data.success);
            };
```

You need to adapt, this method show you how send data PHP to JS regards.

Comment: thank you, I tried what you suggested, for some reason the page gets refreshed after pressing the submit button and I don't get to see the data at the console. What can cause to that?

Comment: also while checking the js file in sources tab, the run dosen't get into the `xhr.onload` block so i cant get the `console.log(data);` object data. what can cause to that?

Comment: Why i don't use this code to do an ajax request? Because this is an old code and not Cross Browser. I suggested using ajax lib from jquery or ... for example gave you the best choice for Cross Browser ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

You can also send the response inside a "body" key-value pair, and put the success/error indication inside the HTTP status code:

```
$success["body"] = "You request just sending to the server ...";
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK", true, 200);
```

And receive it in js:

```
xhr.onload = function(data) { 
    console.log(data.status);
    console.log(data.body);
};
```

see:
[Set Response Status Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163970/set-response-status-code)

or:
http://php.net/manual/de/function.http-response-code.php

explanation of codes:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Thank you. Tried it like so `try {
            $query->execute();
             if (!$query) { 
                 echo "Failure conncting db!";
             }else{
             $success["body"] = "You request just sending to the server ...";
     header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK", true, 200); 
    }
         }`   but for some reason i cant understand.  the run dosen't get into the xhr.onload block so i cant get the console.log(data); object data. what can cause to that?

Comment: Hmmm if the backend crashes, it would eventually send a status code like 500 internal server error. If the request keeps in pending state, the backend might be deadlocked in a loop or something...