# How to Json Response don't change again?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, if-statement

my code (edited)

```js
function loadJSON(){
    var user = document.getElementById("userid").value;
    var server = document.getElementById("zone").value;
    var data_file = "https://api-xyz.com/trueid/mobilelegends/?id="+user+"&zone="+server+"&token=NguyenThuWan";
    var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    try{
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e){
    try{
        http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
        }
    catch (e){
    try{
        http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    catch (e){
        alert("Your browser broke!");
        return false;
        }
            }
    }
                
    http_request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
        if (http_request.readyState == 4 && http_request.status == 200  ){
            document.getElementById("nickname").innerHTML = jsonObj.nickname;
            }
        else (http_request.readyState == 4 && http_request.status == 200  ) {
            document.getElementById("nickname").innerHTML = jsonObj.error_msg;
            }
        }
    http_request.open("GET", data_file, false);
    http_request.send();
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Get Nickname and Error Message</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>ml nick</h1>
        <p>please input userid = 105740419 zone = 2547 for correct json response</p>
        <p>and annother value to get 404 response</p>
        <input type="tel"  id="userid">
        <br/>
        <input type="tel"  id="zone" onchange="loadJSON()">
        <br/>
        <div>Nickname : <span id="nickname"></span></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

from the snippet above, I want to get a 404 error message from JSON response (not undefined) in the same element with "nickname",
I'm stuck for a couple of days
I was trying to custom else code like

```
else {
    document.getElementById("nickname").innerHTML = "please check again!;            
}
```

after seconds it changes to undefined,

200 results:

```
{
    "result": {
        "status": "200",
        "Author": "Nguyen Thu Wan"
    },
    "nickname": "Yepe vs Everybody",
    "userid": "105740419"
}
```

404 results:

```
{
    "result": {
        "status": "404",
        "Author": "Nguyen Thu Wan"
    },
    "error_msg": "Invalid Id or Zone"
}
```

Please Help, it's too complicated for me.
is it possible what I want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to find out if XMLHttpRequest.send() worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876123/how-to-find-out-if-xmlhttprequest-send-worked)

Comment: You are only checking the [`XMLHttpRequest.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState), which doesn't tell you the returned HTTP Status Code. You should [`XMLHttpRequest.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status) (in combination with `XMLHttpRequest.readyState`) to determine that.

Comment: @Ivar where should i put it?

Comment: The top answer linked in my first comment shows an example. First you need to check if `xmlhttp.readyState === 4`, then inside this `if` you can check whether the response status is 200 or 404 or whatever you please.

Comment: @Ivar i've tried to change some, but didn't work

Comment: @Ivar add response on my post